# Opening Files for Edit

Tags: c, file, filestream

I am having some trouble with a basic file opening. I can't successfully initiate the filestream. It keeps coming back NULL... Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I created a "test.dat" file in the same directory that the source code lives.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) 
{
    if((cfPtr = fopen("test.dat", "rb+")) == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be in the current directory. In case of MSVC it's would be the directory of the project file.

Comment: Your code compiles? You didn't even declare a type for `cfPtr`.

Comment: I included just a snippet of the code. I corrected the directory and all is well. 'Slipped my mind! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `test.dat` file to the directory where the compiled .exe lives, or if the current directory for the application is somewhere else, place the file in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to open a file, your OS will look in whatever the process *current directory* is. This may or may not be the same directory as where your source file lives, depending on your OS and/or IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio? You have to put `test.dat` into the `Debug` directory. There are two debug directory in newer version, you have to check that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the errno to get a hint as to what is going wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> /* new */

int main (void)  
{ 
    if((cfPtr = fopen("test.dat", "rb+")) == NULL) { 
        printf("File could not be opened.\n"); 
        printf("Errno = %d\n, errno) ; /* new */
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Also, something like `perror("fopen")` would give you a human readable error message.